# AmCharts 4 Maps GeoJSON custom map showing from outside

Tags: javascript, geojson, amcharts, amcharts4

I've been struggling to create a custom map that will overlap the default map with more information. I created a GeoJSON file with the coordinates of the borders as seen on this QGIS screenshot: [Custom North Nigeria on QGIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OORuC.png) but when bringing that GeoJSON file and using it on the actual map with the polygonseries, it uses the "negative" of this polygon, i.e. it assumes this map is all the world outside of this polygon, leaving the inside of the polygon empty [Custom North Nigeria on AmCharts4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPdij.png) (you can see in brown below the actual map loaded from the worldLow series.

Here is the GeoJSON I'm importing.

```js
var map = {
  type: "Feature",
  properties: { name: "North Nigeria", id: "NG-TEST" },
  geometry: {
    type: "MultiPolygon",
    coordinates: [
      [
        [
          [3.5873, 10.2659],
          [3.6797, 10.1398],
          [3.9833, 10.1398],
          [4.3446, 9.7394],
          [4.4541, 9.7023],
          [4.4363, 9.4576],
          [4.4531, 9.4279],
          [4.5795, 9.4205],
          [4.6298, 9.3315],
          [4.6634, 9.2945],
          [4.7222, 9.2574],
          [4.7473, 9.1981],
          [4.7724, 9.1461],
          [4.806, 9.1165],
          [5.0, 9.161],
          [5.1515, 9.0942],
          [5.2017, 9.0127],
          [5.2438, 9.0052],
          [5.3533, 8.9904],
          [5.5217, 8.9608],
          [5.6729, 8.8421],
          [5.8242, 8.7457],
          [6.1191, 8.7531],
          [6.2957, 8.6864],
          [6.4211, 8.4713],
          [6.5638, 8.3527],
          [6.6643, 8.2266],
          [6.8082, 8.3823],
          [6.7534, 9.2129],
          [6.981, 9.2351],
          [7.149, 9.1165],
          [7.2932, 9.2796],
          [7.4955, 9.2945],
          [7.5633, 9.3538],
          [7.6053, 9.3241],
          [7.8072, 9.2574],
          [7.9005, 9.3538],
          [7.9761, 9.3167],
          [8.0011, 9.2574],
          [8.0931, 9.1461],
          [8.0926, 9.0646],
          [8.1515, 9.0497],
          [8.2617, 9.1536],
          [8.3964, 9.1239],
          [8.4548, 9.0423],
          [8.5728, 9.0423],
          [8.6668, 9.2425],
          [8.6673, 9.3167],
          [8.6257, 9.3983],
          [8.5337, 9.5021],
          [8.56, 9.643],
          [8.6288, 9.8432],
          [8.6388, 10.0657],
          [8.6651, 10.1918],
          [8.7841, 10.3104],
          [8.9275, 10.3104],
          [8.9601, 10.1695],
          [8.9843, 10.0212],
          [8.9841, 9.9915],
          [9.1446, 10.0286],
          [9.2029, 9.9322],
          [9.2277, 9.8655],
          [9.1677, 9.7394],
          [9.3016, 9.5985],
          [9.5541, 9.5392],
          [9.7483, 9.5837],
          [9.7487, 9.6356],
          [9.8335, 9.6949],
          [9.8175, 9.8061],
          [9.86, 9.8432],
          [10.557, 9.5021],
          [10.6333, 9.5466],
          [10.7342, 9.5243],
          [10.8951, 9.6059],
          [11.0383, 9.5911],
          [11.5696, 9.6059],
          [11.9169, 9.7765],
          [11.9449, 10.0434],
          [12.1728, 10.0657],
          [12.3692, 10.2882],
          [12.6233, 10.3771],
          [12.7086, 10.4587],
          [12.7847, 10.4735],
          [12.9715, 10.5699],
          [13.1311, 10.5106],
          [13.257, 10.4587],
          [13.3425, 10.5477],
          [13.4232, 10.9333],
          [13.6935, 10.9481],
          [13.7783, 10.9778],
          [14.0519, 11.2299],
          [14.3834, 11.3857],
          [14.5877, 11.5043],
          [14.6482, 11.5933],
          [14.6102, 11.8825],
          [14.6482, 12.1569],
          [14.4818, 12.3275],
          [14.2034, 12.3571],
          [14.0703, 13.0394],
          [13.6067, 13.6845],
          [13.336, 13.6919],
          [13.1732, 13.5733],
          [13.0543, 13.5436],
          [12.8582, 13.4546],
          [12.8067, 13.4027],
          [12.6703, 13.336],
          [12.6103, 13.2841],
          [12.5586, 13.2173],
          [12.5069, 13.158],
          [12.4638, 13.0987],
          [11.8737, 13.2544],
          [11.5535, 13.3508],
          [11.2576, 13.3731],
          [10.9782, 13.3657],
          [10.6564, 13.3508],
          [10.4866, 13.3063],
          [10.2494, 13.2841],
          [10.1986, 13.2767],
          [9.9856, 13.1506],
          [9.7633, 12.943],
          [9.7032, 12.8614],
          [9.5929, 12.8317],
          [8.7647, 12.8985],
          [8.5463, 13.0542],
          [8.159, 13.247],
          [7.8043, 13.3212],
          [7.7282, 13.3286],
          [7.4648, 13.2025],
          [7.2269, 13.0913],
          [7.0573, 13.0394],
          [6.8463, 13.1061],
          [6.6874, 13.336],
          [6.275, 13.6474],
          [5.5485, 13.8773],
          [5.2433, 13.8254],
          [4.8198, 13.7883],
          [4.4552, 13.6919],
          [4.302, 13.5436],
          [4.2001, 13.4695],
          [4.1238, 13.4546],
          [3.9516, 12.8021],
          [3.6377, 12.5425],
          [3.618, 11.8306],
          [3.4978, 11.2819],
          [3.7083, 11.1261],
          [3.7584, 10.9481],
          [3.7579, 10.8073],
          [3.8167, 10.7405],
          [3.8416, 10.607],
          [3.7145, 10.4661],
          [3.5789, 10.2882],
          [3.5873, 10.2659]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }
};
;
export default map;
```

And I'm using it as I would use any of the other provided maps:

```js
/*....*/
import nigeria from "./maps/countries/nigeriaNorth";
/*....*/
    let countriesSeries = chart.series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries());
    countriesSeries.useGeodata = true;
    countriesSeries.geodata = nigeria;
/*....*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of the Geopoints matters for AmCharts.

Use ".reverse()" on the Geopoints array, and the map will look fine.

(Didn't find a way to reverse the order that QGIS exports the Geopoints though)